# How can I write this CSS more efficiently?

Tags: css

This code works but I suspect that it is not the way it should be written:

```
.srtbl-qt  {
    text-align: left;
}

 caption { text-align: left;
}
```

I tried writing it like this but it didn't work

```
.srtbl-qt caption {
    text-align: left;
}
```

What is a good way of writing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a comma to seperate selectors:

```
.srtbl-qt, caption {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: use comma to seperate selectors

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
.srtbl-qt,
caption  {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate several selectors with a comma:

```
.srtbl-qt, caption 
{
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this by concatenating them using a comma:

```
.srtbl-qt,caption  {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Do note that  comma in CSS selector is used to separate multiple selectors that have the same styles

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can think of your .css files as Libraries in which you can reuse classes. By Creating one class such as '.left' in this example, you could apply this class in both html tags that require text-alignment to the left.

styles.css

```
.left {
text-align: left;
}
```

page.html

```
<body>
<p class="left">paragraph</p>
<img src="picture.jpg" class="left" />
<section class="left otherClass">This is a section</section>
</body>
```

CSS is designed for RE-USE, so re-use classes that achieve the same thing rather than writing one with a different name. Each tag can have many classes, the one that appears last will override any class that has a collision (same style) inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
.srtbl-qt, caption {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Take less lines, and give the same results. So I think it's the most efficient way.